# How to return a 401 error response via Struts?

Tags: java, struts

I have a method with a return type **ActionForward**, and need to return a 401 response in certain situations. How/what can I return from this method to give the desired result?

```
public ActionForward doExecute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ...

    if (some sort of error situation){
        // need to return a 401 here
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there something that you could do by setting the redirect flag on ActionForward?

Comment: I was thinking that, but had no success so far. Not really used Struts before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I've just sent a response via the response object, as above, and returned null immediately after.